# Set particular value for a month of data based on column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, setvalue

I have a dataframe made up of daily data across a number of columns;

```
            A B C D
01/01/2020  12 3 2 1 
02/01/2020  8  14 5 1
03/01/2020  45 4 1 3
.
.
.
.
31/12/2021  5 1 5 3
```

The data is generated automatically but I would to be able to overwrite data by month or by date.

I understand something like this could reset a value but is there anyway to do it in bulk by month  or between two certain dates?

```
df.set_value('C', 'x', 10)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` first and the set values in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), also here working [partialy string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) for set values of month:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)

df.loc['2020-01-02','C'] = 100
df.loc['2020-01','B'] = 500
df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-01-02','A'] = 0
#select multiple columns by list
df.loc['2020-01-03':'2021-12-31', ['C','D']] = 1000
print (df)
             A    B     C     D
2020-01-01   0  500     2     1
2020-01-02   0  500   100     1
2020-01-03  45  500  1000  1000
2021-12-31   5    1  1000  1000
```